# Is there a benchmark results for mining with monero using different cpu and gpu's?

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining

Is there a list of how much each cpu or gpu can hash when mining monero? I read that cpu is better at mining monero than gpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will help you 
https://www.servethehome.com/monero-mining-benchmarks-select-dual-intel-xeon-e5-systems/

And I can tell you on my hardware 
2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz I got ~ 430 H/s